# How to show only one AR object at a time on Achor?

Tags: java, android, arcore

i want to show only one object at a time on an achor. Currently i'm getting my AR model from a server at runtime and showing my model. when i tap on anchor pin points every time i got the new AR model so i have to many model after some taps(equals to number of taps). i want restrict the model at once. every time  when user taps on the screen ar model always shows only one object at a time.

```
public class ARObjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private ArFragment arFragment;
private String Asset_3D = "";
String imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a_r_object);

    arFragment=(ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    imageUri = intent.getStringExtra("arImageUri");


    arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) ->
            placeModel(hitResult.createAnchor()));


}

private void placeModel(Anchor anchor) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

                        ModelRenderable.builder()
                                .setSource(ARObjectActivity.this, RenderableSource.builder()
                                        .setSource(ARObjectActivity.this, Uri.parse(imageUri),
                                                RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
                                        .setScale(0.5f)
                                        .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
                                        .build()
                                )
                                .setRegistryId(Asset_3D)
                                .build()
                                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNoteToScene(modelRenderable,anchor))
                                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ARObjectActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage()).show();
                                    return null;

                                });



            }


}

private void addNoteToScene(ModelRenderable modelRenderable, Anchor anchor) {

    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    //anchorNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
   // arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);

    // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
    TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());

    //set rotation in direction (x,y,z) in degrees 90
    node.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), 90f));

    node.setParent(anchorNode);
    node.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    node.select();



}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this new method

```
private void clearAllModel() {
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getChildren());
    for (Node node : children) {
        if (node instanceof AnchorNode) {
            AnchorNode tmp = (AnchorNode) node;
            if (tmp.getAnchor() != null) {
                tmp.getAnchor().detach();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it at

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
    clearAllModel();
    placeModel(hitResult.createAnchor()));
}
```

Explanation:

as you can see, everytime you tap and `placeModel` into `addNoteToScene` is called, there is this line of code

```
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

all your existing model (which is on anchorNode) is under this `arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene()` as a child

with my method suggestion, the first time there is 0 child (null). So it will move on and just do `placeModel` and then it has 1 child.
On second time it remove that 1 child, and `placeModel` is called again, and make it 1 child again. And so on ... so, there will be only 1 child (model)

Comment: thanks buddy, i have a question that is my model re-render when user click and my object override the other object ?

Comment: thanks buddy, its works perfectly :* you save my a lot of time, :)

Comment: I am not really sure about the re-render / not. But for the object i think it doesn't override. `detach()` method removes it from the Session [ARCore Anchor Public Methods](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Anchor#public-methods_1) @AhsanSyed

Comment: thanks once again buddy. you not  just solve my problem also explain it